# Vite+React+TS project load assets but the body page is empty

Tags: reactjs, nginx, deployment, vite

I created a Vite+React+TS projects. I'm deploying in a AWS Ubuntu through a NGINX server. The index.html and the resources are sent but the page is in blank. You can access it through "http://www.servername.com/lionmiss-hub" (for privacy reasons I don't want to reveal the real domain)

Hi everyone!

I created a Vite + React + TS projects. I'm deploying in a AWS Ubuntu through a NGINX server. The index.html and the resources are sent but the page is in blank. You can access it through "www.servername.com/lionmiss-hub" (for privacy reasons I don't want to reveal the real domain).

I was thinking it could be base url issues. However, the assests and resorces are loaded properly. When I check the html code, the body is empty. In other hand, I have a Vite + Vue in the root domain ([www.servername.com](http://www.servername.com)) and is loaded perfectly.

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {

  # Ports
  listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
  listen 443 ssl;

  # Config Cert
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/servername.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/servername.com/privkey.pem;
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

  access_log /projects/logs/access.log;

  root /projects;

  # Index file
  index index.html index.htm;

  # Server Name
  server_name servername.com www.servername.com;

  ###################
  ## Personal Page ##
  ###################

  location / {
    root /projects/personal-page/dist;
  }

  ##############
  ## LionMiss ##
  ##############

  location /lionmiss-hub {
    alias /projects/lionmiss/hub/dist;
  }

}

server {

  # Ports
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  # Server Name
  server_name servername.com www.servername.com;

  ## Redirect http:// tp https://
  if ($host = www.servername.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  if ($host = servername.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  ## Return Not Found
  return 404;
}
```

/projects/lionmiss/hub/.env

```
VITE_BASE_URL="lionmiss-hub/"
```

/projects/lionmiss/hub/vite.config.ts

```js
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'
import eslint from 'vite-plugin-eslint'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig( ({command, mode}) => {

  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '');

  return{
    plugins: [react()],
    base: env.VITE_BASE_URL
  }
})
```

These are screenshots from the browser console. You can see the body doesn't load divs or any tag.

[image]

[image]

Bye and thanks for helping or advicing!

Answer (score 0):

Yippie Ki-Jay!!!

Ah, ah, I'm going to anwser myself  Finally, I decided to test in local changing the value of "base". Then I realized the console warming about react-router. It is shown messages about the lack of "base" value in the urls, so let's change it ✨

This is the original code

```js
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const theme: ThemeLMH = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.user.theme);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={themeStyle[theme]}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Auth />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<Main />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />}></Route>
            <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />}></Route>
            <Route path="*" element={<Error />}></Route>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Now we are applying the changes only in the first level routes.

```js
function createPath(path: string): string {
  const { VITE_BASE_URL } = import.meta.env;
  return `${VITE_BASE_URL as string}${path}`;
}

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const theme: ThemeLMH = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.user.theme);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={themeStyle[theme]}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path={createPath('login')} element={<Auth />} />
          <Route path={createPath('')} element={<Main />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />}></Route>
            <Route path='contact' element={<Contact />}></Route>
            <Route path="*" element={<Error />}></Route>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I nearly forgot, the links all over the project must change too. In this case, the "/" could be a little joker  The value of VITE_BASE_URL is "lionmiss-hub/", the slash is at the end. Working URLs must prepend an slash at the begining. Let's reuse the "createPath" before and add the "/".

```js
<Link to={`/${createPath('test')}`}>{test}</Link>
// /lionmiss-hub/test
```

I hope you like it. It's very silly mistake which could last you many hours.

Have a nice weekend!